# Use Laravel Sanctum SPA auth and Auth UI together

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have a set up that has a Vue SPA which ordinary users use. I also am creating a system admin area which is not part of the SPA but part of the Laravel application (blade views etc).

Happy with authenticating the SPA as per https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#spa-authentication

However when trying to log in using auth ui (bootsrap) into my admin area which is a blade view I seem to get 302 redirection back to log in page all the time.

Does Sanctum work with web auth middleeware?

My env file is as follows:

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost,127.0.0.1
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
```

Web routes file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
   Route::get('accounts', 'Admin\AdminController@index'); });
```

API middleware in Kernel.php

```
 'api' => [
        EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
```

Comment: I have never used sanctum before, but I think you can use create custom guards. also if you using laravel spatie you can specify role guard

Comment: I will try that. But I would have thought that the auth guard would still work alongside Sanctum.

Comment: @EdenWebStudio I am also having the same issue. Did you find any success? Then please share with me it will help me too much. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SiddharajsinhZala No i did not manage to solve it. Seems that set up doesn't work. I ended not using Sanctum and opting for https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth which I have used before and it works for what I need. Was trying Sanctum for a Laravel based solution.

Comment: @EdenWebStudio Do you have any idea? Can I use Sanctum SPA for Vue and Sanctum token for Admin Panel APIs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SiddharajsinhZala Got this to work by creating a different guard as suggested above.

Comment: Yes it can work, you need to get the csrf-cookie and send it with every request and use the token for authenticated users, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69659750/1304811